# Angularjs-service return value

Tags: html, angularjs

I have service

```
angular.module('myapp')
.service('AnswerService', function() {
    var answers = [];
    this.addAnswers = function(questionId) { 
        answers.push(questionId);
        console.log(answers);
    }
    return this;
})
```

and have to retrieve the value of answers in controller and display it in html.

should I use `return this` or `return answers`?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: should that be 'return this' or 'return answers'?

Comment: i have called addAnswers func in my controller for looping and store the value in array. my issue is i have to retrieve 'answers' array in controller.

Comment: u can return answers

Comment: Depends on what you want to do... Do you want to expose the `addAnswer` functionality, or not?

Answer (score 2):

Add another getter function, like,

```
angular.module('myapp')
.service('AnswerService', function() {
    var answers = [];
    this.addAnswers = function(questionId) { 
        answers.push(questionId);
        console.log(answers);
    }
    this.getAnswers = function() {
        return answers;
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly, beat me to it

Comment: how to call this in controller?

Comment: The same way you would have called 'addAnswers' function. Inject AnswerService to your controller, then do AnswerService.getAnswers();

Comment: it returns with empty array in ng-repeat

Comment: Please share your controller code as well in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access array outside, it should be set to the service.

Add line

> this.answers = answers;

```
angular.module('myapp')
.service('AnswerService', function() {

    var answers = [];
    this.addAnswers = function(questionId) { 
        answers.push(questionId);
        console.log(answers);
    }
    this.answers = answers;
    return this;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.answers = answers;
```

I would return `this`

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this.

```
angular.module('myapp').service('AnswerService', function() {
var answers = [];
this.addAnswers = function(questionId) { 
    answers.push(questionId);
    console.log(answers);
    return answers;
} })
```